# Meaning of units in the Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, units, dimensional-analysis

So we have the inequality $\Delta x\,\Delta p\geq \hbar/2$ Why is the uncertainty of position in meters? Isn't uncertainty measured in probabiliies? Does it make sense to say that the uncertainty in position of an electron is 10 pm? What information we get? 10 pm from where? From the nucleus?

Comment: The uncertainties there are expectation values of operators. Would you care to write down their definition in your question to specify what is obscure to you?

Answer (score 2):

Uncertainties are written with the same units as to what is being measured.

For example, we do an experiment to measure the position of a box with respect to an origin. We measure its position using metre sticks and we get a measurement of $x=2.34$ m. Now of course there are uncertainties in this measurement as always and found out that the uncertainty in this case is $\delta x=0.05$ m.

As you see, the uncertainty is measured in metres as well as this is the "error" of the measurement and not the probability. Therefore we end up with the final measurement of $x=2.34 \pm 0.05$ m.

Comment: Now in your case for example, we measure the position of the electron with respect to something, for example the nucleus. Of course we can't measure with extreme precision and thus only be allowed to measure the expectation value. Since we can't measure the precise position, this leaves to an uncertainty (or the "error") in the measurement.